# How to pass paramater to ajax jquery to call action from another Controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a drop down list size, I need to call action from one controller when i click in button:

How do i call an action edit and pass the value ddlsize to action using ajax jquery.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486132/jquery-ajax-passing-value-from-mvc-view-to-controller

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18185940/ajax-json-calling-mvc4-controller-method-parameter-always-null

Answer (score 0):

You can attach to click event (or onChange) and send an AJAX request like so:

```
<script>

    $('#yourcomboboxid').click(function() {

        // prepare the model as per action parameters
        var model = { SelectedIndex: "2", SelectedValue: "2014" };
        $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Edit", "Home")',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: JSON.stringify(model)
            })
            .success(function(result) {
            });
    });

</script>
```